# Did Aarav and Oviya's relationship start out as a fake relationship?

Tags: bigg-boss-tamil

The first season of the Indian reality TV show Bigg Boss Tamil just got over.  The big scandal of the season was the popular contestant Oviya leaving the show after she attempted suicide.   Here's the background.  In the beginning of the season, Oviya had what seemed to be a romantic relationship with another contestant Aarav (who ended up becoming the winner of the show).  Then she told Aarav that she loved him, and he didn't reciprocate that statement, so she  cut off things there and said "Let's just be friends." Then weeks later, Oviya started making romantic advances toward Aarav again.  Aarav got really irritated by this, told her definitively that he does not love her, and started giving her the silent treatment.  (He also kissed her during this time, but that's another story.) Oviya was psychologically affected by this, feeling betrayed that (in her view) Aarav had led her on all this time and feeling distraught that her love was unrequited. So she attempted suicide in order to get herself evicted from the show, which happened in short order.

Now near the end of the August 3 episode, a few days before Oviya's suicide attempt, Oviya and Aarav had the following conversation (translated from Tamil to English):

> Aarav: Let's make something very clear, now, this moment, right now, OK? There's no love. I'm very clear about it. That's how I've been since the beginning. 
>   Oviya: Then you were cheating me? 
>  
>   Aarav: Yes, cheating you.  OK? You have used that one word... 
>   Oviya: Wait, wait, wait, no, no, no, you didn't cheat me, it was my misunderstanding, you know, that you were loving me, right, so you took advantage.  Is that so? 
>  
>   Aarav: **One matter, during the time when we were in the first week and second week, Raiza and you were sitting here.  Do you remember? "Can we just do time pass, as long as we're here can we do [inaudible], can we fling?"** 
>   Oviya: Yeah? 
>   Aarav: Do you know who said that? Was I saying that? 
>   Oviya: Raiza. 
>   Aarav: You, not Raiza. OK? Remember that first. 
>   Oviya: **At that time there was nothing. At that time love didn't come.** 
>   Aarav: At that time love didn't come for you.  If suddenly love comes for you, that doesn't mean I cheated you. I didn't cheat you or do anything. OK? 
>  
>   Oviya: It was just misunderstanding? 
>   Aarav: It was your misunderstanding. I didn't cheat you. OK? Never use that word.

I'm interested in the parts in bold.  My question is, are Aarav and Oviya admitting that the relationship they had in the beginning of the show was just created for the purposes of the show?  And then that Oviya later developed love for Aarav despite the initially phony nature of the relationship? Or are they simply saying that Oviya just wanted to casually date Aarav in the beginning, but then her feelings grew more intense as time passed?

Have either Aarav or Oviya discussed this after the show got over?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Well, that's what reality shows are! Talking about the Indian shows, majority of them are scripted. I haven't seen Tamil big boss, but I'm awware about the Hindi version. Each season they specifically choose contestants that can hold the season and shoot trp upwards, characters mainly include someone who fights a lot - even in the smallest thing, one who abuses a lot, a couple who "falls for each other" and different others..

Answer (score 2):

The actual reason may be they have done it as a fake one, whether the director may told them to act like that to increase the TRP rating of the channel. So this is common in cinema industry. From my point of view the whole relationship thing is totally fake.

Comment: Well, I think what happened in the last week before Oviya's departure was genuine; she really had feelings for Aarav and he refused to reciprocate, so she really suffered psychological distress as a result.  But I think there's a good possibility that the original relationship they had in the beginning of the show may have been fake, as the dialogue I quoted suggests.

Comment: But they are actors. They may fake it too@KeshavSrinivasan

Comment: Well, it seemed pretty genuine to me.  Oviya's actions and words in the last week seem too erratic and disorganized to be the product of purposeful writing.

Comment: hmmm may be@KeshavSrinivasan